# Amazon Redshift COPY with transformation

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift has a COPY operation that allows you to copy files from S3 into Redshift (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).

The .json files that are in S3 are ``dirty"; they are not ready to be copied into Redshift directly and need to run through a transformation first. My question is; do I need to write the new cleaned JSON files back to S3, then perform the COPY from those cleaned files, or is there a way to run the jsons through this transformation as part of the copy procedure?

Answer (score 7):

@tommy

The COPY operation only allows few simple transformations like DATETIME format changes, NULL placeholders, etc.

To extensively cleanup your data, you may have to write your own program and dump the results back into S3 before it can be copied into redshift.

If your data is small, you can write a simple program using AWS SDK (available in Java, PHP, and Python flavors) to perform the ETL and load it into redshift.

In our case, the data is huge (~400 Million rows a day) so, we use Amazon EMR, HIVE, and SerDe (JSON) codec to create logical HIVE tables, apply transformations using HQL, and dump the cleaned results back to S3 as TAB delimited files. Then, we load the result into redshift using the standard COPY command. We also use Amazon Data Pipeline to orchestrate and automate this workflow.

Ex. HIVE Script

```
add jar s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar; --SerDe codec

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  source_table_name (column_a string, column_b date)  row format 
    serde 'com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.JsonSerde'
    with serdeproperties ( 
      'paths'='column_a, column_b'
   ) LOCATION   's3a://your-bucket-name/source-directory-path/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  dest_table_name (column_a string, column_b date) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LOCATION 's3n://your-bucket-name/dest-directory-path/';

INSERT INTO dest_table_name select * from source_table_name;
```

Of course, the example shown above just re-formats the data. You may have to add additional transformations based on your use case.

Hope this helps.